# Transform html tags from db

Tags: php

I am using a jquery editor.And the content will be saved in the database along with the html tags . That is for example I have typed "aneesh" in the editor and  using editor makes the text bold and italics the saved the content to db .
So the content will be saved in the db along with text and html tags

Now i want take the content from db and want show the text in formated ways that is need to transform the html tags that in my the content want to show like this  ***aneesh***  Is there any way for this  please help me

Comment: Do U try do it self? Do U get some errors?

Comment: what is the problem?? you can simply print it on a `div`

Comment: I don't understand, if snip like this `<b>aneesh</b>` is saved on your database, there will be no problem in displaying it in bold when you `echo` it.

Comment: no while printing it shows along with the tags

Comment: So you want it to be printed not in bold but by exactly the way it is in database?

Comment: no i want to print it bold but it is printing like this <b>aneesh</b>

Comment: ok thanks i have corrected the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can also use htmlspecialchars()

```
$a=htmlspecialchars($a);
<text>$a</text>
```

wud help u save and retrieve the html characters

Answer (score 1):

To store and retrieve html you should use `htmlspecialchars()` - this preserves html tags etc etc when saving and `htmlspecialchars_decode()` - this converts them back to proper html that can be displayed - when displaying the retrieved content.

Storing using this and calling the decode function when populating the textarea behind the wysiwig editor will/should have kept everything preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the data out of database (i'm using PDO): and echo/post the result to the document without string formating:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table;';
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $row['result'];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have content with html tags like i-e `<b>Hello</b>` in the database, and when you return it from the database again, the jquery editor that you are using will automatically remove those tags and will transform your text again and make it i-e bold (if **hello** in case).
There is no need to do anything but just echo it out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javascript for better and easy solution.

get raw html content from db (with php) to show web browser (with javascript): innerHTML or .html() (JQuery)